# Starting client console app through Startup class

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm writing a client-server app with client part in console application and a web api application as a server. How can I trigger launching client console app in my Startup class (inside web api application)

Comment: `Process.Start()` ?

Comment: wow, that was far easier than I expected, Thank you very much, @PanagiotisKanavos